# Can't Reload or manually type a page route with react-router & express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, single-page-application

I'm setting up a single-page App with React router using Express router on the server side (for serving the first index page with the react router and then standing by for API requests). Currently I only have 2 routes: '/' and '/history'

-clicking on "history" link from the home page gets me there without any problems.

-Manually typing "/history" route makes the browser stay on loading forever.

-Reloading the page while being on "/history" makes the browser stay on loading forever.

how can i go about solving this?

I tried rearranging the routes on express, After this I tried setting the app.all('*') method to handle all requests. Finally I tried changing app.all with app.get...,but neither of these help me.

my index.js (for express router):

```
    /*Express Server*/
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const { mongoose } = require('./database');

    //settings
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    //middleware
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    //routes
    app.use('/api/month',require('./routes/monthly.routes'));

    app.use('/history',require('./routes/history.routes'));

    //static files
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

    app.get(async (req,res)=>{
        await res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index'), (err)=> {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
    });

    //Start server
    app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
        console.log(`Server listening on ${app.get('port')}`);
    });
```

router part of my app.js (for react router):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Axios from 'axios';

    import Home from './Home'
    import Latest from './Latest'

    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                RecentExpenses: [],
                monthState: null,
                Total: 0,
                Today: null
            }
        };

        render() {
            return (
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home {...props} Today={this.state.Today} Total={this.state.Total} RecentExpenses={this.state.RecentExpenses} />}  />
                            <Route exact path='/history' render={(props) => <Latest {...props} Recent={this.state.RecentExpenses} month={this.state.monthState} />} />
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What I expect is to always receive the same file from the server, so react router can take on as the navigation router. but it stays loading forever with this being thrown into the node console:

```
(node:8756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it, turns out that it was a routing error. as my history.routes.js was handling the /history requests (with a deprecated part of my code) and it never got to call app.use('*'....).

Bypassing this specific route allowed to get me to serve the index.js and continue the react routing from there. it is a matter of understanding how and when both routings work.

PS: @aquilesb 's answer helped with setting the proper path, for anyone that might have an issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

On your index.js you could replace that:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get(async (req,res)=>{
    await res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index'), (err)=> {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});
```

For that:

```js
app.use(express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public/`))

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    await res.sendFile(`${process.cwd()}/public/index.html`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
});
```

You should be able to access /history without any problem.

Comment: Hi @aquilesb, just fixed it, thanks for the answer and for pointing this out. I also had an additional error in my history.routes, that redirected the /history request to an obsolete part of my code, so this particular route never got to that part. Fixed this and added your corrections and it worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)